# Does each solution need its own .vs\config\applicationhost.config file?

Tags: asp.net, svn, visual-studio-2015

We were re-arranging our repository and were considering having all the solutions files in one of our top level directories.  We have multiple webapps and we are using Visual Studio 2015.  I noticed that in the .vs folder that is created it has this file: applicationhost.config.  My question is that does each webapp need its own applicationhost.config file?  If this is the case then we shouldn't keep all the solution files in the top level directory correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could make one test.

You could create a solution, add multiple projects to it and see if the config file changes after each project added.